# Vue.js – How to allow an user to type only letters in an input field?

Tags: validation, vue.js, input, filter, vue-component

I have an input field, let's call it **firstName**. I want to let an user to type only letters and apostrophes. No numbers and other special symbols. The logic is something like that:

1. On @keydown some method (let's call it "**checkName()**") gets a typed character.
2. Then it checks this symbol if it's belongs to something like **[A-z]**. If belongs, the method does nothing. If not – the method replaces it with **''**. (Also need to add an **apostrophe** to this checking array to let an user to type it too).

How can I realize that? I've looked for a few Vue validators and masks, but haven't found there anything I need. Validators just check an input field, masks suite better, but it's necessary to have a fixed range of string.

Any ideas? Or maybe it's everything much easier and I make it complicated?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you want the user only can type letters, then you can do `v-on:keypress` and check on the event function.

```
<input type="text" v-model="firstName" v-on:keypress="isLetter($event)">
```

then the method:

```js
isLetter(e) {
  let char = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode); // Get the character
  if(/^[A-Za-z]+$/.test(char)) return true; // Match with regex 
  else e.preventDefault(); // If not match, don't add to input text
}
```

Example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/festive-buck-hm4fd?file=/src/App.vue

You can change the regex pattern to `^[A-Za-z\']+$` if you also want to allow apostrophe

I also added computed properties to check if the input value is valid or no in case you still want to allow users to input other than letters and shows error

Comment: This blocks out EVERY key (tab, select all, etc)

Comment: `keypress` is depreciated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/keypress_event, you should use `beforeinput` or `keydown` instead. For me, changing to `keydown` or `beforeinput` did not worked either on mobile.

Answer (score 3):

How about when HTML does that for you?

```html
<input type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z]+">
```

Comment: Using Chrome, pattern will not work for me.

Comment: This is a good suggestion, though it doesn't actually prevent input entry, but instead validates upon form submit attempt. The user can still actually type invalid characters into the field.

Answer (score 0):

Although Owls answer it pretty good, I do think it's important to note that you do not want to break browser defaults when it comes to keyboard input.

You do not want to break tab, delete and backspace and possibly other features.

```js
    onKeyDown(index, event) {
      // Let the browser use its defaults for things like tab.
      if (event.key.length !== 1) return

      // Define your own predicate.
      if (isIgnored(event.key)) event.preventDefault()
    },
```

I ran into this issue when trying to make an accessible version of a digits only input.